# Layout folder images giving 403 forbidden error?

Tags: 2007, error

In my sharepoint site I am getting 403 forbidden error for Layout folder Images.

/_controltemplates/My/_LAYOUTS/1033/STYLES/My/show.jpg

**Most likely causes:
•This website requires you to log in.**

**update:**

/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/ALERTUC/IMAGES/minus.gif also give same error. I think I have some permission issue with /_CONTROLTEMPLATES folde

Comment: Does the file exist at `c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\template\controltemplates\ALERTUC\IMAGES\minus.gif`?

Comment: Yes, does exists. and my folder 12 hive (sharepoint 2007)

Comment: Whatever you do, *DO NOT TAMPER* with permissions within IIS. This is will render your environment unsupportable.

Comment: Also, I do not believe assets are designed to be accessed from within controltemplates like this. Use layouts for these assets - the only things that should exist within ControlTemplates are UserControls (ASCX files).

Comment: It is working other enviroment. but why not this enviroment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead, your path should be

```
/_LAYOUTS/1033/STYLES/My/show.jpg
```

Comment: Samething in other environment (QA) it is working. But in my test environment not working

Comment: /_CONTROLTEMPLATES/ALERTUC/IMAGES/minus.gif also give same error. I think I have some permission issue with /_CONTROLTEMPLATES folder

Comment: take @JamesLove advice and use the layouts folder for images. ControlTemplates is best used for user controls and such. It should work fine sitting in a layouts folder.

Answer (score 2):

_layouts is a virtual directory that is only ever one level below the site you're in, so in your example, the same level as _controltemplates. Your ControlTemplates mapped folder in your solution should not have an _layouts folder. Have a separate mapped folder and access the files there directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just copied the folder (from other location) to *Layouts* folder. This way it may not inherit the correct permissions which is set for *Layouts*.

You should manually create folder inside Layouts and then copy the assets(images) to it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I copied from other location. As you said I created manually folder and copied images. still the same. even I gave folders permission to everyone